# Organizing translation files in angular2

Tags: angular, localization, ionic2, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am working on adding localization support in my ionic2 application. The typescript files in my application are organized in the following folder structure:

> src
>    |- app
>    |- service
>    |- pages
>
> ```
>   |- login
>   |- book-list
>   |- book-details
> ```

The template, css and typescript of a particular page are kept under the corresponding sub-folder under pages folder.

Ideally I will like to keep the translation stuff corresponding to the particular page in the same folder. This way, I will have one translation file per page per language sitting in the same folder as the corresponding template the typescript file. This will make it very easy to update translation text when literal text content of any page is changed.

This may also have benefit of lazy loading page specific translation file and deferring loading of translation file to the point when page is actually being loaded and displayed.

So far all the example I have seen for implementing localization put all the translatable text in a single monolith file (one file per language) or keeping all translation files in a single folder.

Is there a way organize and load the translation files from the structure that I am looking for?

Thanks.